# Dynamics 2013: Filtered Lookup showing only related entities

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In dynamics crm 2013 I want to provide paypal data for individual contacts.

I have a paypalAccount entity, which can be set in a lookup on the contact form.
Now I want to filter the lookup on the contact form, to only display paypal accounts which where ever assigned to this contact.

I do not want the user to see thousands of unrelated paypal accounts when trying to select a different one for a specific user.

Comment: "were ever assigned to this contact" is not a filter-able condition: you can only filter based on actual, present data

Comment: is there a way to add this information to the paypal entity?

Comment: Another entity (bonus: it would allow for the filter you're after... if you restructure the contact, that is)

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-filter your lookup. There are some standard ways to do this, but you can also use FetchXml. A nice article can be found [here](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/03/22/filtered-lookup-approaches-in-crm-2011/).

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a 1:N relationship between these entities. Then that entity just see related entities.